# Keep submenu opened after mouseout

Tags: jquery, css

I want keep submenu opened after mouseout, but when mouseout, this is closes.
The markup is not so important to write it

**My js code is:**

```
jQuery("#test_test").each(function() {
    
    jQuery(this).children(".nav-main-item").mouseover(function() {
        jQuery(this).children(".nav-drop").addClass('active');
    });
    
    jQuery(this).children(".nav-main-item").mouseout(function() {
         jQuery(this).children(".nav-drop").removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

**My css code is:**

```
.nav-main > li > .nav-drop {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 10%;
    left: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    top:0;
    display:none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border-left: 5px solid #f5f5f5;
    margin-top:328px;
    border-top-right-radius:20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:20px
}

.nav-main > li> .nav-drop.active {
    display:block;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Add your HTML too

Answer (score 0):

Remove your mouseout function. As mouse out is removing active class. But removing this will keep all previous sub menus open. is that what you require? to keep all sub menus open, once active